# PerlObjCBridge Better way to read a plist from string (due to Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 encoding error)?

Tags: objective-c, perl, scripting, nsstring, nsstringencoding

This code snippet is an Example that should work on any Mac OS X system.

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
use Foundation;
my $dscl = "/usr/bin/dscl";

sub getGeneratedUID(){
  my $name = shift;
  my $command = "$dscl -plist . -read /Users/$name GeneratedUID";
  print "$command\n";
  my $output = `$command`;
  my $plist = NSString->alloc()->initWithCString_encoding_($output,NSStringEncodingASCII);
  my $data = $plist->dataUsingEncoding_(NSStringEncodingASCII);
  my $record = NSPropertyListSerialization->propertyListWithData_options_format_error_($data,NSPropertyListImmutable,0,0);
  my $array = $record->objectForKey_('dsAttrTypeStandard:GeneratedUID');
  return $array->objectAtIndex_(0)->description()->UTF8String();
}
my $logname = $ENV{'LOGNAME'};
my $guid = &getGeneratedUID($logname);
print "My GUID: $guid\n";
```

So I am writing a perl wrapper for the Mac OS X Directory Service Command Line (dscl) utility. It has to be perl due to the site requirements , and due to the fact that this command has changed its output slighly over the years I am using the ability for it to format its output as an Apple Propertly list. I have used the NSPropertyListSerialization->propertyListWithData in a couple other languages over the years, general idea being that if you convert the string to data this will create a NSDictionary for you from the string, thus the title of the question, is there a better way to parse the plist output. So far this code works, though it does give the following error:

```
2012-01-10 10:57:31.270 perl5.12[1876:1507] Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
```

Which Googling around I realize is this line

```
  my $plist = NSString->alloc()->initWithCString_encoding_($output,NSStringEncodingASCII);
```

So If I can figure out the encoding error then I think this way will work pretty well for me, but if you have a better suggestion of parsing this info I would love to hear it. However I would really like to figureout what encoding or method I should be using to bridge the two strings which I hope is a simple question as I have found similar questions but nothing that deals with this kind of error using the bridge.

So Far I have tried removing the alloc:

```
  my $plist = NSString->stringWithCString_($output);
```

I realize this error is not a fatal one, but I would rather not use this methodlogy until I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, not `NSStringEncodingASCII`.

Comment: Well while you are totally right on the typo, even the correct constant does not work, which did make me check something, If I do however change it to 1 , it works. I am used to being able to call these in the python bridge when I import Cocoa, so I think that is the actual root of the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. The constants aren't always defined via the bridge (it's been a while since I've done a lot of PerlObjC work).